# Unable to aggregate multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've `user` collection which has role object which has roleId. I also have `roles` collection which has id.

Now,for each role, I'd like to get the list of users.

Ex:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Scott",
        "role": {
            "roleId": "123432"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "role": {
            "roleId": "123432"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Scott",
        "role": {
            "roleId": "556432"
        }
    }
]
```

Roles Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123432"
        "name": "admin",
        "type": "internal"
    },
    {
        "id": "556432"
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "external"
    },
    {
        "id": "556432"
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "internal"
    } 
]
```

Now  I want to get all the roles of type `internal` and their related users:

So, the output should be,

```
[
    {
       "role": "123432",
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "Scott",
                "role": {
                    "roleId": "123432"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "John",
                "role": {
                    "roleId": "123432"
                }
            }
        ],
        { 
            "role": "556432",
            "users": []
         }
    }
]
```

I'm doing this with Spring Boot.if someone can help me on how to get this aggregation using spring boot mongo, that'd be very helpful for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute aggregate on your role collection and first filter out role as per your condition. Since you want all `internal` roles, your match stage should be:

```
{
    $match: {
      "type": "internal"
    }
}
```

Now its time to lookup users for each role:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "user",
      as: "users",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "role.roleId"
    }
}
```

I don't know how mongo queries are executed on spring boot but this is how its done on mongo so you can convert it to your language specific code.

Here's a working example on mongo playground.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/I1FPuX971YZ